# EntityManager with createQuery()

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

With Symfony 3, I've often used the createQuery() function from the EntityManager so that I can use SQL statements.

Example:

```
$query = $em->createQuery("SELECT p FROM testcoreBundle:Product p JOIN p.productdetails d");
```

With the Update to Symfony 4 I need to change the entity. I tried the following but it doesnt work:

```
use test\coreBundle\Entity\Product;
...
$query = $em->createQuery("SELECT p FROM :entity p JOIN p.productdetails d");
$query->setParameter('entity', Product::class);
```

I get the following message:

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 14: Error: Expected
> Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_ALIASED_NAME, got ':entity'

Is there a way that I can still use full SQL statements with the QueryBuilder?

Comment: For what it's worth, this is DQL rather than SQL (the distinction is important because you can run SQL as well, but you need different methods). You cannot use input params to alter the underlying query structure, that's actually the whole point. What does "need to change the entity" mean exactly and were did you read about that?

Comment: You are basically trying to use a table name for a prepared variable which SQL does not allow.  Basically only data values can be parameters. `SELECT p FROM test\coreBundle\Entity\Product ...` or some variation on that is what you are looking for. Though like the comment above I would have expected the bundle alias `testcoreBundle` to have worked.

Comment: You are right. The bundle alias in the createQuery-Function works... Why you need to change the notation in getRepository but not in createQuery?

Comment: Back in the days of our ancestors php did not support the Name::class functionality.  You always had to fully type out the complete namespace as a string.  Things like aliases were added just to reduce typing.  But lo, ::class became a thing and much of the alias type functionality went away.

Comment: It's a bit off-topic but there is something to be said for just jumping to the latest Symfony version.  Create a new up to date app and then just start to copy/paste.  You can avoid many strange intermediate things. Just a thought.

Comment: `$query = $em->createQuery(sprintf("SELECT p FROM %s p JOIN p.productdetails d", Product::class));`